# android create array from string and add to array list

Tags: java, android

Hi I'm trying to create a contacts list I have an array of contacts and I'm looping through each one and getting the first character of the last name. I'm then trying to create an array with the value of that character and add it to my final array. Then I want to check if the array already exists in my final array. If it doesn't add it to the array.

The aim being so I end up with an array list of arrays that are going to be headers in a list view. Does anyone know how to create an empty array and name it the value of a string (I'm going to add stuff to this array later)? and then add that to an array list?

Here is what I have tried so far but I'm struggling to get my head round it

```
for (int i=0; i<contactsJSONArray.length(); i++) {
  singleContactDict = contactsJSONArray.getJSONObject(i);
  Log.v("Main", "Contact singleContactDict " + i +"= " + singleContactDict);
  String firstname = singleContactDict.getString("first_name");
  String lastname = singleContactDict.getString("last_name");

  char firstLetterInLastname = lastname.charAt(0);
  Log.v("Main", "firstLetterInLastname = " + firstLetterInLastname);
  headerWithLetterArray.add((firstLetterInLastname).toArray);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

array is something like [a,b,c,d], they don't have names. If you mean JSONArray and you want to store everything is JSONObcject try:

```
parentJson.put(lastname.substring(0,1), new JSONArray());
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try using "Map" for the final collection. Where your first character of the last name can be a key in the map and the real name will become value (value internally can be a arraylist).

When you want to add a new contact to list, you can first look for the key in the map with the first letter. If it is then get the value which is arraylist and add the new contact to that.

In this way you will have lots of arraylist marked by the single letter in map which can be used in loop to fill the list.